# How to automatically launch iOS application when a bluetooth connection is established?

Tags: objective-c, ios, bluetooth, automation, gamekit

So basically what I want to do as the title says is when I have a bluetooth connection established to my iOS device, an application should automatically start. How can I do that?

Observation: GameKit is used for the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without jailbreaking the device and writing/installing a Springboard plugin, this isn't possible in iOS.

There are no Apple-provided APIs for launching apps and developers are only able to write code that runs when their app is launched by a user.

Comment: I thought I heard something to the effect that Apple's MFI program provided a way to make this happen for devices developed under that program.

Comment: That may be true, but I know nothing about it. From my personal experience, no accessory that is part of the MFI program has ever automatically launched an app without my interaction before. That isn't to say that it isn't possible - just uncommon. You'll have to consult someone with knowledge of the MFI program.